# Avoid "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" in a recursive type without as const

Tags: typescript, recursion

I have a pretty complex typescript type, for a function that takes a graph scheme and generates a chainable object from it:

```js
const working = createGraph([
  {
    name: 'a',
    next: [
      {
        name: 'b',
        isRecursive: true,
        next: [
          {name: 'b2'},
        ],
      },
      {name: 'c'},
    ],
  },

] as const);
working.a().b().b().b2();
```

The issue is that without the `as const` keyword, I am getting `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`. I am trying to get rid of the `as const` expression because it's not user friendly in terms of API, and it's very easy to miss it. Also, the `as const` keyword forces me to use literal array, so if I don't define it completely inside createGraph I am losing the intelisense autocomplete, and it's not convenient in large graph schemes.

here is the full implementation of `createGraph`'s type (a link to working playground at the bottom):

```js
export type Descriptor = readonly GraphNode[];
export interface GraphNode {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly isRecursive?: boolean;
  readonly next?: readonly GraphNode[];
}

export function node<T extends GraphNode>(n: T) {
  return n;
}

interface RecursiveGraphNode extends GraphNode {
  isRecursive: true;
}

interface NonTerminalGraphNode extends GraphNode {
  next: readonly GraphNode[];
}

type DescriptorToApi<D extends Descriptor | undefined> = D extends Descriptor 
? ConvertToFlat<{[p in keyof D]: D[p] extends GraphNode
  ? {[y in D[p]['name']]: () => D[p] extends NonTerminalGraphNode
    ? D[p] extends RecursiveGraphNode
      ? DescriptorToApi<[...D[p]['next'], D[p]]>
      : DescriptorToApi<D[p]['next']>
    : undefined}
  : undefined}>
  : undefined

type ConvertToFlat<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? T['length'] extends 0
  ? {}
  : ((...b: T) => void) extends (a: any, ...b: infer I) => void
    ? {[P in keyof T[0]]: T[0][P]} & ConvertToFlat<I>
    : [] : never;

export function createGraph<T extends Descriptor>(descriptor: T) {
  const api: DescriptorToApi<T> = {} as any; // mock implementation, all we care about is the type
  return api;
}
```

[here is working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAiwDOBjKBLMGaOAXjimAEMATCAOwBtE4BxKSsACwDkJrgA2gF0A3AChQkWHDx0YwKADNK2VGw48+qAN5i45KrUbM6lALbAAXHEwx8dAObj9FGvSYzMAJWDYArlCYeABuwAD81gBGEBAMVHTOBm7GcHSgMBFJRh7qXLz8wuIAvmIS4NDwin502DB49KlaADwAKnDpwHTUmKzseVoAfAAUdNYtAJRwui7AMAF0qcWlsvJKKqg+-oEhwLma-O0g8l09e-k6ep6bAUGh1nZ+wEtiKwrKqnC8dC0KZrKUDDOWkOx26vQ05ymlzSR2srmyzCBBVEYhKYiQKHQWFwBCIUBaEAAgmA8E00CDOmCMDh8IRiAAfODVfiKWTAagDUjoCknLE03HEMRhOAAYXooVgBIAYgxKDAmtoBGAZAsANbARAQRToITWNBKoQ8sFI4CXYWK5iydAGgQAclMFltQl1cCGkxInP1YENHV5Xx+UD+pkBfX2pv0+mFXp9R0pPWu21CJsuEbgUextLxBOJpIEADoC9G7TCYE6ADTW71CAYpiN6jMC-FEklkm329JOmup6zM4CstLUEr6HtdPtswdduAjlnj0oY1BiugSmDS2XylqcshtX1g+HuZiUOiIYRpuAtO1xRwwThOo09AAMZqmQ6nrqGBbzkTG7s5wQgeGoSYdx6IZKGsQ9EArD8vxVRQFDgABJH84D-ADa3NAQAAUVTgdVNW1c972dMYBCIrChCKOAADJRXFBQVwgGU5SaBDJ2HOAT2sNIJXEMopEqapanqBZcCoeQ9laO8+RxOkoGGfh+Vk78oX0bB6FsOAODwetFKzZtSQ3LltEoygeggxIKDmKAFi054AHo7NIEhnJc1y3PcjzPLIeQNK8vyPNKNS6A0ugIBgAB1aBVVkBwuVEuVdlDIYBFraZU1ScwrDgW1KFtMta30EtrBS9L0u0B0sttSI8quXwbh2e4oEeCsio4grSojcrMusKqACZbRfDq4Ao-Khv0LqLB67ABvaoRayKfKhHGQL1PgUKIqimLep0mS8S5NrUzS1MKp63LRvS1qSrGibKuqis8G8OrEyyh5gBa9Jivaoabp6yJ+sGjqRq+zqTuy6aAf0ObUwWsQUXi8SkvWyKoGixxesmBzLPmMyj14oKNIAd02xw4tcBGNGS1L2tBnK8upj6Duumm7tqrZbhepq3tSBmrrGkHuuyv6Zr5oG+Z+sHhfSqGIxh2HNJ6fGYGWomUZivNKDdT9NcibXtd6t1SjEIA)

Comment: Pretty sure that as const assertion is required. Without it the type isn't inferred how you need it to be.

Comment: Is there a friendly way to hint users of the lib that they need to use `as const`?

Comment: You can check if the provided array is readonly. If it isn't, provide a helpful error message encouraging the use of as const.